# How do I calculate functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ where it applies that $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+i\cdot v(x,y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I calculate functions $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ where it applies that $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+i\cdot v(x,y)$?

$z=x+iy$

$f(z)=\bar{z}+z\cdot Re(z)$

So then I put in $f(z)=x-yi+(x+yi)x=x-yi+x^2+xyi $

But how can I know what is from here u and what is v?
Do i need to guess that or?

I know that v is complex conjugate function, but how do I recognize it from here?

Is it connected maybe with x or y, for example $x(1+x)+y(x-1)$ or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z=x+iy$, and $f(z)=\bar{z}+z\operatorname{Re}(z)$, then
$$f(z)=f(x+iy)=\underbrace{\overline{x+iy}}_{\bar{z}} + \underbrace{(x+iy)}_{z}(\underbrace{x}_{\operatorname{Re}(z)})$$
$$=x-iy+x^2+ixy$$
$$= (\underbrace{x+x^2}_u)+i(\underbrace{xy-y}_v)$$
So
$$u(x,y)=x+x^2$$
$$v(x,y)=xy-y$$

Comment: But is u=x+x^2?

Comment: Yes. Just because $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ doesn't mean the $y$ has to appear in it. For example, $u$ could just be constant. $u$ is the real part of $f$ and $v$ is the imaginary part of $f$ (both regarded as functions of the real variables $x$ and $y$, not of the complex variable $z$).